# how to select all news entries and all comments to him in one query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Reply question*
[Fetch all news and all comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787561/fetch-all-news-and-all-comments)

You really think this best way?

I`am also needed get all news for current user [authorId]=>99
example

```
$news = array(
[0] = array(
[id]=>1,[authorId]=>99,[data]=>"Lorem Ipsum"
),
[1] = array(
[id]=>2,[authorId]=>99,[data]=>"Lorem Ipsum"
)
);
```

and get all comments for this user
example

```
$comments = array(
[0] = array(
[comId]=>1,[newsid]=>1,[authorId]=>99,[data]=>"bla bla bla bla"
),
[1] = array(
[comId]=>2,[newsid]=>1,[authorId]=>99,[data]=>"bla bla"
)
);
```

other table users

```
$users = array(
[0] = array(
[userId]=>99,
[userName]=>"User99"
)
);
```

and after

```
select * from news n left join users u on n.authorId = u.userId where n.authorId = 99
```

into this select push select for get comments

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        [id] => 1 // news' id
        [userId] => 99,
        [data]=>"Lorem Ipsum",
        [comments] => array(
            [0] => arra(
                [comId] => 1 // comment's id
                [userId] => 99
                [data]=>"bla bla"
            ),
            ...
        )
    ),
    ...
)
```

in question***(top)

> The first query gets all of the news articles and puts them in an array. The second query gets the comments, and accumulates a separate array within each news article's structure.

But if this queries and foreach two array be run 10000 times while
example 
10000 refresh page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a logical caching

1) If you get many records and limit considered paged query result

2) Separate information for each table in different arrangements

```
$user = array();

$comments = array();
```

3) Combines both arrays using foreach and array_merge

```
$merge = array();
$i=0;
foreach ($comments as $row) {
   extract($row);
   if(in_array($iduser, $user)):
     $merge[$i] = $comments + $user;
   endif;
$i++;
}
```

This is a pseudo code have not tried it maybe should do some adjustments. I hope you serve